# Editing external CSS

Tags: css

I am looking for support editing stylesheet of my website

**I have the below in the file main.css**

```
.bg-danger, .bg-success {
    padding: 0 5px;
}

a {
    color: #EF1F2F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**Then there is a header file header.php with the following code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?=isset($title) ? $title : null;?></title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
</head>
<body>
```

My requirement is to change the background, font etc.
I am not familiar with working on stylesheets. Requesting support from other members.. Thanks in advance

Comment: can u explain what is not working? is the css not loading at all? 
then you maybe got the wrong path... otherwise i would asume that you maybe made a mistake with the css classes. But we need the html code as well to help you.

Comment: actually, everything is working good.. but I am looking to make some changes, like the background, font etc.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Into your main.css file you can start with adding some minimum properties like :

```
body {
  background-color: #yourHexCodeColor;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}
```

Then learn the very basics of css right here => https://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/getting-to-know-css/

Comment: thanks for the response.. I tried and there is no change in the appearance. It looks like, the page appearance is all from <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">..

Comment: As Legarndary suggested, you have to override the existant styles. To do so, you could add '!important' after your properties values like : body {background-color: #FF0050 !important;}… But it could hard if you have a lot of style to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't edit CSS code coming from an external source.
So what you have to do is to overwrite the styles you need to be changed in another stylesheet. In your case, it would be the main.css file.

So if there is a style in the bootstrap file that looks like this:

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

You can make a copy of that style in your own file (main.css) and change the value. So in your file, you have this:

```
body {
    background-color: #f7f7fe;
}
```